# Button does not add an item to a selectManyList

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF page with a `h:selectManyList` and a Primefaces `commandButton`. I want to add new elements to the list when I click the button. The button's action method is called, but elements don't show up in the list. I probably just don't see the forest for the trees.

Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:messages id="errors"/>
        <h:selectManyListbox id="listBox" value="#{testBean.availableThings}" style="width:100%">
            <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selectedThings}"/>
        </h:selectManyListbox>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton id="adder" value="Add" action="#{testBean.addThing}" 
            ajax="true" update="listBox" process="@this listBox"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
@com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping(
    id = "testbean",
    pattern = "/testbean/",
    viewId = "/pages/general/testbean.xhtml")
public class TestBean {
    private List<SelectItem> availableThings;
    private List<String> selectedThings;

    public TestBean() {
        availableThings = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedThings = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getAvailableThings() {
        return availableThings;
    }

    public void setAvailableThings(List<SelectItem> list) {
        this.availableThings = list;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedThings() {
        return selectedThings;
    }

    public void setSelectedThings(List<String> list) {
        this.selectedThings = list;
    }

    public void addThing() {
        availableThings.add(new SelectItem("item", "item")); // I get this message
        System.err.println("Added item");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the added item appear in the list and what do I need to do to make it appear?

Comment: Because nowhere you add a new element to `selectedThings`. You change `availableThings`... Please debug things a little.

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes... I want to add new items to the list, I don't want to change what's selected (if anything). Maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: You add them to the wrong list.... And you **do** change what is selected...

Comment: And most likely you reversed the fields in the xhtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reversed the fields in the xhtml.

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="listBox" value="#{testBean.availableThings}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selectedThings}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Should be

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="listBox" value="#{testBean.selectedThings}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.availableThings}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```